# Styling Qt Model/View items based on their ItemDataRole properties

Tags: qt, stylesheet, model-view

I have a `QTreeView` with items from my own model (`QAbstractItemModel` derived). Now I would like to style the items (with a stylesheet on the `QTreeView`) so that depending on various properties they would have various backgrounds.

Also it seems that this problem applies to any Model/View containers. Not just `QTreeView`.

---

For example doing alternate backgrounds is easy. `alternatingRowColors` on the `QTreeView` has to be `true`. Then in stylesheet you may use `:alternate` pseudo-selector to change properties for the alternate items so:

```
QTreeView::item {
  background: green;
}

QTreeView::item:alternate {
  background: blue;
}
```

---

Doing selected items is similarly simple. In fact doing anything that is handled by Qt's pseudo-selectors is easy.

But what about properties that are not pseudo-selectors? In particular how to select style based on values associated with `ItemDataRole` (which seams to be the only reasonably generic method of storing data in models)?

*Note that there is a trick. If for example you do not use checked state you might "reuse" that state to map to something of your own and then you have a pseudo-selector for it... But this is just a workaround and not even a general one.*

---

With `QTreeWidget` it seems you can go by having a dedicated `QWidget`-derived class for the items where you would add `Q_PROPERTY` with whatever you want. Then you can access that property by name in the stylesheet.

See for example ["Using custom Q_PROPERTY with Stylesheet" question on Qt Centre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/30095-Using-custom-Q_PROPERTY-with-Stylesheet) and ["Trigger an update for the widget while using dynamic properties." note at the end of Qt Style Sheets Examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html).

But the `*View` classes do not have any `QWidget`s or even `QObject`s for their items (or at least not public accessible ones).

---

There is also possibility to provide own `QAbstractItemDelegate`, possibly one derived from `QStyledItemDelegate`. But that makes stylesheet interaction a bit harder.

With simple staff like `background-color` property it seems doable. But how would you simulate `border-image`, `padding` and many other styles in complex sets?

Not to mention that once you write an item delegate the code is frozen. If `Qt` changes ways of rendering stylesheet (improves it somehow) you will not benefit from it... Also is makes logic/presentation separation a bit harder. Now you need a programmer to style those items, not just a CSS-enabled graphics-guy...

---

So is there any way to subclass in stylesheet based on model-provided properties/data?

Comment: I found a similar question on a different forum (http://lists.qt.nokia.com/public/qt-interest/2010-May/023771.html). But it is a bit old now and with little activity so I thought about asking it here again. Hoping for more constructive or knowledgeable answers.

Comment: Another question trying to achieve similar effect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982351/using-multiple-qstyleditemdelegate-with-stylesheets with a negative answer.

Comment: Due to lack of activity here I asked the question on Qt Centre (see http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/53210-Styling-Model-View-items-based-on-their-ItemDataRole-properties) and got a negative reply (cannot be done) from "wysota".

Comment: Sad story, and sadly I'm also facing this problem now... Thank you for the follow up story.

Comment: Is the answer that you cannot do it, that you would need to use a custom delegate for this?

Comment: @neuronet Yes, it is so.

Comment: @AdamBadura if you wrote an answer to your question it might help some of us... :)

Comment: The link http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html is dead. Maybe http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-using-dynamic-properties still contains what you referred to?

Comment: @equaeghe It looks as if that what you provide could be a solution. Although is anything but `bool` supported? Since examples show only `bool`. However now I'm long time in a different project, no Qt anymore. So it is hard to check.

Comment: @AdamBadura I was just pointing out a dead link... I'm not very knowledgeable about Qt.